# How to center div columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap div, which might have 3 columns or 2 columns or 1 column based on a condition. As the number of columns are less I need to center them in the outer div . How can I achieve it?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">3</div>
    
    </div>
```

Based on the condition, I might have only div 1 and 2, or only 1 or all 1,2,3. Is there any way that I can always make the div's position in center irrespective of the columns? and not float them to the left

Comment: you can use col-md-4 col-md-offset-4. it is center column.

Answer (score 3):

Add a special class to the rows you want to be centered..

```
.row.col-centered > [class*='col-'] { 
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/p2L9Q6NKip

Answer (score 2):

This will be easier way. This will work everywhere.

CSS:

```
.col-lg-4 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or you can use flexbox (but i see no reason to use it here).

```
.col-lg-12 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: @Roberrrt I believe he was talking about the `margin: 0 auto`, not the `flexbox`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap's `text-center` class on the outer div:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
```

Comment: It is not center column. align center